# Android appflow deploy doesn't update device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-appflow

I'm using appflow with Ionic 4. I have built, and packaged my app for android, and assigned it to my master channel.  I have then downloaded the apk, then installed using `adb install ../path_to_apk`.

The app runs fine on my android device (samsung A7).

However if I make a change and push this to the same master channel, I am expecting the app to update.  I installed the relevant pluggins as per the documentation:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic --save \
--variable APP_ID=“caf97139” \
--variable CHANNEL_NAME=“Master” \
--variable UPDATE_METHOD=“auto”
```

Am I correct in assuming the app should update? I can't find any android specific instructions for appflow deployments.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the copy and paste for the cordova install had used the wrong type of "".

I changed my package.json from

```
"cordova-plugin-ionic": {
   "APP_ID": "“my_app_id”",
    "CHANNEL_NAME": "“Master”",
    "UPDATE_METHOD": "“auto”"
```

to

```
"cordova-plugin-ionic": {
   "APP_ID": "my_app_id",
    "CHANNEL_NAME": "Master",
    "UPDATE_METHOD": "auto"
```